# How to sort the date array of objects in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to make the normalized date object. Right now I have

```
  const data = [{
    createdDate: '2019-01-06T14:39:33.564Z',
  },
  {
    createdDate: '2018-01-07T14:39:33.564Z',
  },
  {
    createdDate: '2018-01-07T14:39:33.564Z',
  },
  {
    createdDate: '2019-01-06T14:39:33.564Z',
  }]
```

this is the record of when the user is registered on the system. So according to the following i need to make the number of users by year, by month of that year, by week of the selected month of the year
I need to sort this array into something like:

```
const updatedData = [
  <year>: [
    <month>: [
      <week number>: {
        count: <number of users registered>
      }
    ]
  ]
]
```

So far I tried to make it in this way, but something is missing and cannot figure out what is and how to make it. Please can you explain it, would really appreciate it?

```js
const data = [{
    createdDate: '2019-01-06T14:39:33.564Z',
  },
  {
    createdDate: '2018-01-07T14:39:33.564Z',
  },
  {
    createdDate: '2018-01-07T14:39:33.564Z',
  },
  {
    createdDate: '2019-01-06T14:39:33.564Z',
  }
]

const updateData = data.map((item, index) => {
  const date = new Date(item.createdDate);
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const month = date.toLocaleDateString('default', {
    month: '2-digit'
  });
  return {
    [year]: [{
      [month]: {
        userCount: index,
      },
    }, ],
  };
});
console.log(updateData)
```

Comment: `.map()` won't group things for you. It just changes each item separately.

Comment: any idea other than map then>

Comment: FYI, what you are asking for is _not_ "sorting".

Comment: You want something like `.reduce()`

Comment: It should be called sorting, because the output should be like for all 2019:[01,02,03...12] months count the userrs. and for 2020, and so on, but in my case it is not sorting but it is showing all in a seperate obj

Comment: _"It should be called sorting"_ - no, it should not. Sorting is the process of changing the _order_ of items (without changing the items), not of transforming one _structure_ into a different one.